# Looping over ILookup, accessing values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got a `ILookup< string, List<CustomObject> >` from some linq I've done.

I'd like to now iterate over the results:

```
foreach(IGrouping<string, List<CustomObject>> groupItem in lookupTable)
{
    groupItem.Key; //You can access the key, but not the list of CustomObject
}
```

I know I must be misrepresenting a `IGrouping` as a `KeyValuePair`, but now I'm not sure how to access it properly.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`ILookup` is a list of lists:

```
public interface ILookup<TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
```

So because `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is (implements)...

```
IEnumerable<TElement>
```

...a lookup is

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TElement>>
```

In your case `TElement` is *also* a list, so you end up with

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<List<CustomObject>>>
```

So this is how you can loop through the customers:

```
foreach (IGrouping<string, List<CustomObject>> groupItem in lookupTable)
{
    groupItem.Key;
    // groupItem is IEnumerable<List<CustomObject>>
    var customers = groupItem.SelectMany(item => item);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Each entry in ILookup is another `IEnumerable`

```
foreach (var item in lookupTable)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
    foreach (var obj in item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

A simple example:

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 };
var lookupTable = list.ToLookup(x => x);
var orgArray  = lookupTable.SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();
```

Comment: I can't seem to make a IEnumerable.Select on the item though. It's inner item comes up as another IEnumerable - Should this work? item.Select( currentCustomObject => new OtherCustomObject(test.Name))

Comment: In fact, I can't use a foreach on it either. That 'var obj' is a list.

Comment: @Jono `lookupTable.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y)).ToList()` should give a list of customObj. See the edit for a short example

Answer (score 0):

I create an enumeration using the keys first, which I find easier to follow.

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = lookupTable.Select(t => t.Key);
foreach(string key in keys)
{
    // use the value of key to access the IEnumerable<List<CustomObject>> from the ILookup
    foreach( List<CustomObject> customList in lookupTable[key] )
    {
        Console.WriteLine(customList);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Wrong, the value is `IEnumerable<List<CustomObject>>`. That said, pointing out that a lookup can be accessed by an indexer is useful information.

Comment: Yes, thank you, an IEnumerable of lists. I have edited the post to reflect your correction.